# Visual Studio 2010: Solution Explorer not showing project directory structure

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, directory-structure, solution-explorer

I'm using a new install of MS Visual Studio 2010 and cannot seem to get the Solution Explorer to show the project directory structure (instead of a just list of all files in the project for each project in the solution). There is no "show all files" button.

Any ideas on where I might find the option?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is how I resolved it:

There is no way to do this for the entire solution. You have to select each individual project in the Solution Explorer and click the `Show All Files` icon for each one, and then the folder structure shown will be that of your directory structure.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2005 where is Show All Files ?

Answer (score 14):

Try with this shortcut:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

You can also access View and select Solution Explorer

Comment: Gave it a shot, but although Solution Explorer shows, it doesn't update the directory structure as desired. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 2):

You must add a project to your solution , in your visual studio first go to:

*File* --> *New Project* --> *Choose your Project type*

and in the bottom of new project window there is a solution option, change it from "*Create new solution*" to "***Add to solution***".

After that your solution explorer expanded and solution node will be added to solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following ULR and perform action based on the setps.

[Refere Here and its working for me](https://allinworld99.blogspot.in/2015/06/visual-studio-error-no-exports-were.html)

Comment: It's a good idea to include relevant information in your post. At least a high-level summary. External links expire.